# NSCache giving me (null) all the time

Tags: objective-c, nscache

I am saving NSString to NSCache but is giving me (null) at NSLog.

I have this code to save at NSCache after i initialise it at ViewDidLoad

```
cache=[[NSCache alloc]init];
```

Then i have a function that is called and saves objects

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
 NSString *res = [cache objectForKey:indexPath];
 if (!res) {                      
     res=@"1";
     [cache setObject:res forKey:indexPath];
 }
```

Then i am checking like this:

```
NSString *res = [cache objectForKey:indexPath];
if (!res) {    
    res=@"1";
    [cache setObject:res forKey:indexPath];
}
```

Unfortunately...

```
NSLog("%@",res); //always it gives me (null)
```

Anyone had this issue before? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where are you doing the logging? Have you checked that the initial value is not NSNull? Does copying the key make a difference (NSCache doesn't copy the key by default)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving  objects check like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
NSLog(@"%@",[cache objectForKey:indexPath]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help the issue was that the indexPath was not the right one! Anyway my mistake thanks guys! :)